# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null" error on resetting google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

below is how i render the google recaptcha unto specified containers (I have 4 google recaptchas on a single page, one on each form)

call the google recaptcha API

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

render it to the specified containers

```
<script>
var recaptcha_susu;
var recaptcha_payrollloan;
var recaptcha_sme;
var recaptcha_personalloan;

var myCallBack = function() {
    recaptcha_susu = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_susu', {
      'sitekey' : 'mysitekey', //Replace this with your Site key
    });

    recaptcha_payrollloan = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_payrollloan', {
      'sitekey' : 'mysitekey', //Replace this with your Site key
    });

    recaptcha_sme = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_sme', {
      'sitekey' : 'mysitekey', //Replace this with your Site key
    });

    recaptcha_personalloan = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_personalloan', {
      'sitekey' : 'mysitekey', //Replace this with your Site key
    });



  };

</script>
```

and then validate it through ajax (this is working like i got true or false), below is one of the 4 forms in the page (on submit function)

```
$("#sme_application_dialog form").submit(function(e){
    //validate the captcha
    $.ajax({
       url : $("body").attr("data-link") + "/validate-recaptcha",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       type: 'post',
       beforeSend: function(){
            $(".whiteblur").fadeIn(200, function(){
                $(".windows8").show();
            });
       },
       complete: function(){
            $(".whiteblur").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $(".windows8").hide();
            });
            $('#recaptcha_reload').click();
       },
       success: function(data){
           if($.trim(data) === "true"){ //this is the part of resetting the form
               var widgetId = grecaptcha.render("#recaptcha_sme");
                grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
           }else{

           }
       }

    });
    //end validation

    e.preventDefault();


});
```

so as you can see from the above reference, if response data contents "true" then reset the google recaptcha but unfortunately, it doesnt work, instead I got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null". Any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations?

Comment: `grecaptcha.reset(widgetId");` you are having a `"` double quote here. Is this a typo or what?

Comment: @Jai: ow my bad, thank you for pointing out, its a mistype, anyway i remove the double qoute and yet still not working. any ideas?